# Extjs dom manipulation

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to move div3 in front of div2 without loosing event handlers?

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='1'>.......</div>
  <div id='2'>.......</div>
  <div id='3'>.......</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of methods:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element

See: insertBefore/insertSibling

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var ct = Ext.getBody().createChild({
        cn: [{
            id: 'item1',
            html: 'Item 1'
        }, {
            id: 'item2',
            html: 'Item 2'
        }, {
            id: 'item3',
            html: 'Item 3'
        }]
    }), moved = false;

    Ext.get('item3').on('click', function(){
        if (moved) {
            console.log('click');
        } else {
            Ext.get('item3').insertBefore('item2');
            moved = true;     
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Content is already rendered the way I described. I want to cut/paste div3 so it moves before div2 keeping the handlers. I don't want to insert a fresh content.

Comment: Did you even bother to try it? Full example above.

Comment: I tried it yesterday on the laptop. I was so surprised that it's working that I went to check the sources also. (Sorry i couldn't write it earlier but an excavator during technical maintenance tore a cable and I had electricity problems + no internet the whole evening)